# Copying newest files to a preexisting directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a few directories

`/home/imp/imp/msgs`

And

`/home/imp/imp/msgs/bak`

The first thing that happens is that all the files (`*.BRD` and `*.MIX`) in `/home/imp/imp/msgs/`get copied to `/home/imp/imp/msgs/bak`

And when a message is posted, They get copied back to `/home/imp/imp/msgs/`

What i'd like to do is copy the newest file(s) (`*.BRD` and `*.MIX`) from `/home/imp/imp/msgs/` to `/home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/`

Is this possible?

I have a shell script that is ran before the files (`*.BRD` and `*.MIX`) are copied from `/home/imp/imp/msgs/` to `/home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/`

```
#!/bin/bash

export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy
nice -n 20 dosbox -noconsole -c "mount c /" -c "c:" -c "cd \\home\\imp\\imp\\" -c "set PATH=c:\\home\\imp\\imp\\" -c "imp-mail scan" -c "set FIDOCONFIG=c:\\home\\imp\\hpt\\config\\config" -c "hpt pack scan" -c "exit"
rm /home/imp/hpt/flags/hpt.lock
/home/imp/imp/pktdate -c /home/imp/hpt/pkt-out/*.pkt
cd /home/imp/hpt
./hpt pack scan
```

It imports the `*.BRD` and `*.MIX` files to `/home/imp/imp/msgs/`

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing that happens when? What message? What files?

Comment: When I start the shell script. The files are *.MIX and *.BRD files.

Comment: What shell script?

Comment: Sorry. Should have included it in the post. This is the script:

Comment: It's invisible. Please include in the question anyhow. [Edit your question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/351267/edit)

Comment: What does this script have to do with your question?

Comment: Just that it's the origin of the files. Other than that, it doesn't really matter. Not sure why I included it. Brain fart, I guess.

Comment: Please edit your question to include only the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of your directory structure, but something like the following should work.

```
find /home/imp/imp/msgs/ -maxdepth 1 -newer FOO_FILE -name '*.BRD' -o -name '*.MIX' -execdir cp {} /home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/ \;
```

### Explanation

- `find /home/imp/imp/msgs/`: Find in the this directory
- `-maxdepth 1`: Don't enter subdirectories
- `-newer FOO_FILE`: Only find files newer than FOO_FILE
- `-name '*.BRD' -o -name '*.MIX'`: With name `*.BRD` or `*.MIX`
- `-execdir cp {} /home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/ \;`: Copy these files to `/home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/`

Probably best to test that it matches the correct files first, by running it without the last part, i.e.

```
find /home/imp/imp/msgs/ -maxdepth 1 -newer FOO_FILE -name '*.BRD' -o -name '*.MIX'
```

Comment: Is it possible to change `FOO_FILE` to a wildcard?

Comment: Not directly. `-newer` just takes one argument. Alternatively, you can just `ls -lt` first. Or use it as a substitution (not trivial to deal with all kinds of characters, but something like `$(ls -t FOO* | head -1)`).

Comment: @ignatius Please let me know if that doesn't work. Otherwise, if this answers your question, please accept it (click the checkmark on the left).

Comment: It doesn't work. But, that's ok. I figured something else out. Thank you.

Comment: @ignatius Great! Please post up your answer (and accept it) so that other people can benefit from it. Also, out of interest, what failed in my answer?

Comment: I needed to be able to use a wildcard as a target.